# Return a string from a Service already running using Remoting

Tags: c#, windows-services, remoting

im trying to use .Net Remoting to get a value of a variable that i use in a thread of an windows service.

```
TcpChannel tcpChannel = new TcpChannel(9998);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel, false);
Type commonInterfaceType = typeof(MyNameSpace.Core.Engine);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(commonInterfaceType,
                                                                "CopyFilePercentage",
                                                                WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
myEngine = Engine.EngineInstance;
myEngine.Start();
```

But it seams that every time that i use the Client to get that value, a new thread is created returning an empty string.

Any idea why is this happening or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Miguel de Sousa

Answer (score 1):

`WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall` creates a new instance of your class for each call. try `WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton`

**EDIT**

Maybe you should read about [client activated objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650208.aspx). Turn your singleton object to a class factory and return a new instance of a real worker class(ofcourse inheriting from `MarshalByRefObject`) which will be used by the client.

so your client will be something like this

```
var worker = client.GetWorkerClass();
worker.GetSomeData();
```

and you will have *one server object* per connection (this may not be the correct terminology).

Comment: but again the object from which, I want to take the value is already created

Comment: ok I gave up and just put a global variable... not that pretty but done the job.

 thanks again

Answer (score 0):

well i just used a [Global Variable Class](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable) not really what I wanted but does the job.

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains global variables for project.
/// </summary>
public static class GlobalVar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Global variable that is constant.
    /// </summary>
    public const string GlobalString = "Important Text";

    /// <summary>
    /// Static value protected by access routine.
    /// </summary>
    static int _globalValue;

    /// <summary>
    /// Access routine for global variable.
    /// </summary>
    public static int GlobalValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _globalValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _globalValue = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Global static field.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool GlobalBoolean;
}
```